# Best way for filtering BIG data with QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

I need advice before I start writing a program.
I have a huge amount of data (~15m lines, 300 MB txt file. 10 simple numbers per line separated by space, each line is unique sequence of numbers).
This data is fixed and does not change.

I need to filter this data under various conditions. (Example search for all sequences that have three of ten numbers identical or find all sequences with the same sum etc.).

What is the recommended way for this task in QT C++ way?
Where to begin? What to do with data? Keep it in a txt file and load from there or insert them to SQLite. What are the recommended ways to complete this task?

Comment: This is basically general C++ question but the solution can be implemented with Qt framework too.

Answer (score 0):

300 megabytes is not a lot of memory to use for an application. TXT file is easiest, but you can use anything. You can simply read the data in C++ and process it.

Filtering based on criteria can be usually optimized. But each requirement has a different optimization. So there isn’t one algorithm that is fast for all criteria.

You can start with the incremental approach, go through all lines and validate the criteria:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 15000000; ++i)
{
  read_line();
  if (check_criteria())
    save_result();
}
```

And then research optimization solutions that could work for all cases.